# printing order when process running parallely

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am running 2 process parallel using python `multiprocessing` and synchronising them using semaphore. Following is my sample code

```
def process1():
    acquireSema()
    dowork()
    releaseSema()
    print "sema released"

def process2():
   acquireSema()
   print "sema acquired"
   dowork()
   releaseSema()
```

I start `process1` first and then `process2` using python `multiprocessing`. My question is my `print` statement is out of order. I am getting following output

```
sema acquired
sema released
```

Shouldn't the order be reversed of `print` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you start process 1 first, then process 2.  But you have done nothing to ensure that process 1 acquires the semaphore first.  It could easily be the case that process 1 gets a bit of time to run but has not yet acquired the semaphore, then process 2 runs to completion.

If you want to make sure process 1 runs before process 2, you need to wait to start process 2 until process 1 has acquired the semaphore.  But of course at that point you may as well just wait for process 1 to run to completion before starting process 2.

Comment: But I think when semaphore is released by python it automatically increments counter to 1 and then only it will be acquired by other process. I am using default internal counter 1.

Comment: @prattom: I have re-worded my answer to hopefully be more clear.  It's not about the number inside the semaphore, it's about whether it is "locked" or not.